# I am unable to use a Type Provider on a localhost for an Android Emulator

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, f#, type-providers

I am unable to use a Type Provider on a localhost for an Android Emulator.

This doesn't work for me when using F#'s Type Provider because the TypeProvider establishes a connection at design-time.

**The Type Provider is happy when I use localhost**

```
[<Literal>]
let JsonPath =   "http://localhost:48213/api/cars"
type Repository = JsonProvider<JsonPath>
```

However, I receive a *connection refused* when attempting to use the localhost path. Details about this error can be found [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1199/how-to-make-our-remote-host-127-0-0-1-reachable-from-android-device-monoandroid-using-vs2010).

As a result, I believe the resolution is to use an alternative IP address:

[10.0.2.2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1199/how-to-make-our-remote-host-127-0-0-1-reachable-from-android-device-monoandroid-using-vs2010)

**The Type Provider is NOT happy when I use 10.0.2.2**

Replacing *"localhost"* with *"10.0.2.2"* on the IP address results in a compilation error stemming from the TypeProvider not establishing a connection to the updated IP address.

The following code will not compile when I attempt to use "10.0.2.2" as the alternative IP (AKA: workaround) which is the required IP for the emulator to work:

```
[<Literal>]      (* "10.0.2.2" is the workaround IP for local host *)
let JsonPath =   "http://10.0.2.2:48213/api/cars"
type Repository = JsonProvider<JsonPath>

type Car = { Make:string ; Model:string }

let getCars() =

    Repository.Load JsonPath
    |> Array.toSeq
    |> Seq.map(fun x -> { Make=x.Make ; Model=x.Model })
```

In conclusion, how can I access a file via a WebAPI service run locally, and still keep the Type Provider happy when executing the Type Provider on an Emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static parameter you provide when you create the `JsonProvider` is purely for design time, in order for it to generate you the types. When you call `Repositor.Load` this will be the uri you use for runtime. They should be treated separately, like this:

```
[<Literal>]
let DevelopmentJsonPath =   "http://localhost:48213/api/cars"

type Repository = JsonProvider<DevelopmentJsonPath>

type Car = { Make:string ; Model:string }

let runtimeUri = "http://production.mycompany.com/api/cars"
let getCars() =

    Repository.Load runtimeUri
    |> Array.toSeq
    |> Seq.map(fun x -> { Make=x.Make ; Model=x.Model })
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart. However, the compiler complains at design-time when plugging in "10.0.2.2". Hence, I think that IP doesn't exist yet until the emulator is launched.

Comment: I had it backward =) So if you use localhost to get the type provider to work and compile. Then set the `runtimeUri` to what you want at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I ran into another issue in which my screen goes completely black with no data. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700086/type-provider-hangs-app-when-loading-data-from-localhost